# Is there a proper way to convert dataframe column containing in each row comma separated strings to a dictionary?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary, iteration

| ID | Genre |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Drama, Comedy |
| 2 | Action, Science Fiction, Suspense |
| 3 | Horror, Suspense |
| 4 | Comedy |
| 5 | Action, Drama, Sports |
| 6 | Comedy, Science Fiction |
| 7 | Drama |

I have a Pandas dataframe with around 10000 rows, these above are the first 7th rows. I would like to create another dataframe or a dictionary that will count the occurrence of every genre existing in the dataset.

Something like this:

| Genre | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Drama | 3 |
| Comedy | 3 |
| Action | 2 |
| Science Fiction | 2 |
| Suspense | 2 |
| Sports | 1 |

Ps. In the original df there are more then this 6 genres.

I have an idea how to do it iteratively with a for loop:

```
my_dict = {} 
for elem in df['Genre']:
    for genre in elem.split(','):
        if genre in my_dict:
            my_dict[genre] += 1
        else:
            my_dict[genre] = 1
```

However, is there any way to achieve this using NumPy or Pandas functions? As with 10000 rows it takes a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df['Genre'].str.get_dummies(', ').sum()
```

Output:

```
Action             2
Comedy             3
Drama              3
Horror             1
Science Fiction    2
Sports             1
Suspense           2
dtype: int64
```

Or, maybe less efficient:

```
df['Genre'].str.split(',\s*').explode().value_counts()
```

Output:

```
Drama              3
Comedy             3
Action             2
Science Fiction    2
Suspense           2
Horror             1
Sports             1
Name: Genre, dtype: int64
```